# SQL Select statement - The thing i am querying for has a single quotation mark

Tags: sql

Hi everyone I am new to StackOverflow and SQL. I am not sure how to phrase the title so google was not very helpful.

I am doing a simple SELECT query:

```
SELECT * FROM Department WHERE DepartmentName = "Controller's Office"
```

I would like to return all results that has DepartmentName of "Controller's Office". The name itself has a single quotation that must not be removed(because boss said so). Using single quotation marks does not work. and returns an error:

```
Invalid column name 'Controller's Office'.
```

How can i do the query so that it works? If you are doing anything complicated please explain because i am new thanks!

Comment: Escape it with a backslash `"Controller\'s Office"`

Comment: If you are using a programming language with an API into MySQL, use its provided method for escaping quotes.

Comment: @Michael ...or better yet, use parameterized queries :)

Comment: @Michael I am not using MySQL, but SQL Management studio 2008.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I am using parameterized queries, String.Format. So i will need to know how to get the \ or ' in the middle of my parameter..

Comment: String.Format is *not* parameterized queries! Use SqlParameters.

Comment: @Theone If you are using parameterized queries, you do not need to do anything special: simply set the value of the parameter to a string with a quotation mark. This is how the APIs that I've seen handle it, both in Java and in .NET.

Comment: opps my bad i thought String.Format is a parameterized query.. The msdn and guides i seen on google do not show me the code view of it. I am doing ASP.Net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most variants of SQL (you don't specify what you are using) will let you escape single quotes using *another* single quote:

```
SELECT * FROM Department WHERE DepartmentName = 'Controller''s Office'
```

Double quotes (in most of the variants of SQL that I know) are used to delimit *identifiers* (column and table names) that contain characters that are not otherwise valid in an identifier's name.

Comment: Thank you this worked fine! By the way, I am using String.Format because the user will be finding this from a DropDownList in ASP.Net. How do i insert an additional ' in the middle of it?

Comment: @theOne - you shouldn't be dropping values like this into your SQL directly - instead, use a parameter: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.aspx